# Convert Date to Minute and Minute to Date in Angular/Express

Tags: angularjs, express

This is my uebersetzer.service.js:

```
module.exports = function (app, Uebersetzer) {


    app.post('/rest/uebersetzer', function (req, res) {
        var uebersetzer = req.body;

        console.log("before" + uebersetzer.zeit);
        uebersetzer.zeit = timeToMinutes(uebersetzer.zeit);
        console.log("after" + uebersetzer.zeit);
                Uebersetzer.create(uebersetzer, function (err, result) {
                    res.json(result);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    app.get("/rest/uebersetzer/:id", function (req, res) {
        Uebersetzer.findById(req.params.id, function (err, uebersetzer) {
            console.log("get uebersetzer by id before" + uebersetzer.zeit);
            uebersetzer.zeit = minutesToDate(uebersetzer.zeit);
            console.log("get uebersetzer by id " + uebersetzer.zeit);
            res.send(uebersetzer);
        });


    });

    function timeToMinutes(time) {
        var hours = time.getHours * 60;
        var minutes = time.getMinutes;
        time = hours + minutes;
        console.log(time);
        return time;
    }
    function minutesToDate(minutes) {
        var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        var minute = minutes % 60;
        var date = new Date(1, 1, 1970, hours, minute, 00);
        console.log(date);
        return date;
    }
};
```

Uebersetzer.controller.js

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module("PassportApp")
        .controller("UebersetzerController", UebersetzerController);

    function UebersetzerController(UebersetzerService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.addUebersetzer = addUebersetzer;
        vm.removeUebersetzer = removeUebersetzer;
        vm.selectUebersetzer = selectUebersetzer;
        vm.updateUebersetzer = updateUebersetzer;
        vm.uebersetzer = {};

        function updateUebersetzer(uebersetzer) {
            UebersetzerService.update(uebersetzer, function (response) {
                findAllUebersetzers(setAllUebersetzer);
            });
        }

        function selectUebersetzer(uebersetzerId) {
            UebersetzerService.findUebersetzerById(uebersetzerId, function (response) {
                vm.uebersetzer = response;


            });
        }

        function removeUebersetzer(uebersetzerId) {
            UebersetzerService.removeUebersetzer(uebersetzerId, function (response) {
                findAllUebersetzers(setAllUebersetzers);
            });
        }

        function addUebersetzer(newUebersetzer) {
            UebersetzerService.createUebersetzer(newUebersetzer, function (response) {
                findAllUebersetzers(setAllUebersetzers);
            });
        }

        function findAllUebersetzers(callback) {
            UebersetzerService.findAllUebersetzers(callback);
        }

        function setAllUebersetzers(uebersetzers) {
            vm.uebersetzers = uebersetzers;
        }

        findAllUebersetzers(setAllUebersetzers);
    }

})();
```

Uebersetzer.html

```
<h1>Uebersetzer</h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Sprache</th>
        <th>Zeit</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input ng-model="controller.uebersetzer.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input ng-model="controller.uebersetzer.sprache" class="form-control" placeholder="Sprache" type="text"/>
        <td><input ng-model="controller.uebersetzer.zeit" class="form-control" placeholder="Zeit" type="time"/>
            <button ng-click="controller.addUebersetzer(controller.uebersetzer)" class="btn btn-primary">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
            <button ng-click="controller.updateUebersetzer(controller.uebersetzer)" class="btn btn-success">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="uebersetzer in controller.uebersetzers">
        <td>{{uebersetzer.name}}</td>
        <td>{{uebersetzer.sprache}}</td>
        <td>{{uebersetzer.zeit|minDate|date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="controller.removeUebersetzer(uebersetzer._id)" class="btn btn-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </button>
            <button ng-click="controller.selectUebersetzer(uebersetzer._id)" class="btn btn-info">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have "app.post" with two Console commands. The console.log shows me before my date ("before 1970-01-01T00: 11: 00.000Z"), but after conversion it just shows NaN. My role for this is timeToMinutes ().

In "app.get" the minutes come from the database, and I change it into a date. My two give console.log "get uebersetzer by id before 100" and "get uebersetzer by id Sun June 24 1906 01:40:00 GMT + 0200 (Central European Summer Time)", but it is not in the input-field in html accepted, although the other data is written from the database in the fields (name and sprache).I hope it's not too much code or too little. I apologize for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake inside your timeToMinutes function. `getHours` and `getMinutes` are functions so you will need to call the functions with `()`. It should look like this:

```
function timeToMinutes(time) {
    var hours = (new Date(time)).getHours() * 60;
    var minutes = (new Date(time)).getMinutes() ;
    time = hours + minutes;
    console.log(time);
    return time;
}
```

Comment: So i had it before, but there was an error "TypeError: time.getHours is not a function"

Comment: time.getHours is not a function, but time.getHours() is :)

Comment: I meant, of course getHours (). But the error is still there

Comment: I tested my updated function again and the function is not returning "NaN". So it is working. The other function does not return the right time but it also does not return "NaN". So where exactly does it fail?

Comment: The error occurs at two variables minutes and hours. I have set the two variables to 60 (var hours = 60; var minutes = 60), then it worked.

Comment: Have you tried **(new Date(time)).getHours() * 60**?

Comment: Thank you! That was the mistake :)

Comment: If my answer is the correct solution, you can always approve it :) Thanks :)

Comment: I Did it. Thank you :)